# ListBox WPF: change foreground color of SelectedItem and keep Material Design?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, material-design, listboxitem

How can i change the forground color of the SelectedItem without removing the Style from Material Design ?

This Works but will remove the Style from Material Design:

```
<ListBox TextElement.Foreground="Black">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

How can i add the Style insted of Replacing it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change Style to BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}"

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />                               
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    </Style.Resources>
      </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```